# Why do I have this error Call to a member function contains() on array spatie laravel-permission

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-permission

In my RoleAndPermission seeder I have

```
        $admin = Role::create(['name' => 'admin']);
     
        Permission::create(['name' => 'create-attribute']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'delete-attribute']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'edit-attribute']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'update-attribute']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'view-attribute']);
        Permission::create(['name' => 'store-attribute']);
        $admin->givePermissionTo([
            'create-attribute',
            'view-attribute',
            'delete-attribute',
            'edit-attribute',
            'update-attribute',
            'store-attribute'
        ]);
```

I have created AttributePolicy

```
public function viewAny(User $user)
      {
        return $user->hasPermissionTo('view-attribute');    
      }
```

And in Auth service provider gate

```
 public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Gate::define('view-attribute', [AttributePolicy::class, 'viewAny']);
    }
```

and in my AttributeController

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if (Gate::allows('view-attribute')) {
        return Inertia::render('Admin/Attribute/Index', []);
        }
    }
```

but when i try to access attribute index page as an admin i get error Call to a member function contains() on array. I know it is problem with **return $user->hasPermissionTo('view-attribute');**
but i don't know why, can somebody help me please?

Comment: In which file and on what line is this error reported (I assume somewhere inside the framework files)? Have you tried to dump the values throughout the functions in the stack trace to identify where a wrong parameter might have been passed?

Comment: It is in attribute policy line return $user->hasPermissionTo('view-attribute'); because when i write return $user->hasRole('admin'); and not use gate just middlware can on my rout it works. But in my database it said that admin have this permissions and this user have role admin.

Comment: it says Error Call to a member function contains() on array App\Models\User::hasDirectPermission D:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\vendor\spatie\laravel-permission\src\Traits\HasPermissions.php:285 @El_Vanja